# Bash provide options and pass variable on choice

Tags: bash, ssh, bash-scripting

Trying to give an option to users of an installer to chose either "Development" or "Stable". By default the installer does "git checkout 1.1.0", but I'm turning 1.1.0 into `$GIT_VERSION` and trying to make a clean way to set that in the beginning.

Trying to set `$GIT_VERSION` to `master` or `1.1.0` with option of 1,2, or 3 (3 being quit). I've got a rough start of what I'm trying to do...

```
PS3='Do you want to install Lastest Stable or Latest Developement: '
options=("Stable" "Developement" "Quit")
select GIT_VERSION in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $GIT_VERSION in
        "Stable")
            $GIT_VERSION=1.1.0 
            echo "Installing 1.1.0..."
            ;;
        "Developement")
            $GIT_VERSION=master
            echo "Installing latest developement version..."
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: specifically, this is wrong: `$GIT_VERSION=master` -- don't put the sigil on the left-hand side of the assignment.

Comment: Also asked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/22239152/1126841 (which is the correct site for this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something like

```
#! /bin/bash
names=(Stable Developement)
versions=(master 1.1.0)
select option in "${names[@]}" Quit ; do
    if (( REPLY > 0 && REPLY <= 1 + ${#names[@]} )) ; then
        if [[ $option != Quit ]] ; then
            git checkout ${versions[REPLY-1]}
        fi
        exit
    else
        echo Invalid reply.
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to simply set the value (master or 1.1.0) as a variable to be inserted into the say, `git checkout $Variable_Name` statement later? The git portion of the script comes much later as I've got all the user input at the beginning.

Comment: Sure, just store the value to a variable: `branch=${versions[REPLY-1]}`.